# UIAlertController buttons are not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I have an Objective C project and want to show some alert to user, On some iPads the UIAlertController buttons are not visible, i have attached an image below.
Any one faced an issue like this? any workarounds?

**Device Details**
iOS 14.4
iPad Air 2

**sample code used**

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@“Alert” message:@“Message” preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction *yesAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@“YES” style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){
            
           
        }];
        UIAlertAction *noAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@“NO” style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){
        }];
        [alert addAction:yesAction];
        [alert addAction:noAction];
        [alert show];
```

**image**

[image]

Comment: please ensure once are you used the any category to replace the color or used any tint color globally to change the buttons,

Comment: exactly my issue! about 1500 iPads of our customer work well and only one iPad mini displays empty buttons. I can reproduce the issue only if I change some Accessibility settings, like "Contrast". But I still have no idea what is going wrong...

Answer (score 0):

this looks weird enough.
But I think the problem is that you are calling the `show` method.
And you need 'presentViewController' because it is no longer `UIAlertView'` but `UIAlertViewController`.

Please use my snippet.

```objectivec
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
                        //button click event
                    }];
UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];
[alert addAction:cancel];
[alert addAction:ok];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

For a more in-depth study, I recommend this [article](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/uialertcontroller-changes-in-ios-8/)